# Different authentication method for different modules in NancyFx

Tags: .net, authentication, nancy

I have a web application consisting of five Nancy modules. The authentication in based on `Nancy.Authentication.Forms`.

I would like to add another `NancyModule`. For that module only, I would like to use stateless authentication.

How may I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by enabling the appropriate authentication method on a per request basis in the bootstrapper. You can use the RequestStartup method for this. Then, in your modules, just call this.RequiresAuthentication method. Since the bootstrapper already loaded the appropriate authentication mechanism, the module just authenticates with whatever mechanism was enabled. Are your trying to build an api and forms front end in the same project?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I wanted to add some API calls to a front end project (although I normally avoid that -- this is a special case)...

Comment: I had the same issue. Best on your project